# Integration in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

Consider $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, a continuous function and not null, i.e, $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x\in A$. Show that $\int_{A} f(x) dx=0$ implies $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in A$.

When I saw this question seemed easy, but try, seemed not very direct.

Comment: What kind of set is $A$ and what kind of integral are we dealing with?

Comment: @zhw. $A$ is a closed block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming $A$ has some sort of regularity, in that it contains an open ball of the right sort. (If $A$ has measure zero, the result is certainly false.)

Suppose $f(x) \not\equiv 0$. Then there is a point $a$ with $f(a)=b>0$. Then continuity of $f$ implies that, given $0<\varepsilon < b$ there is an open ball around $a$, contained in $A$, of radius $\delta$ such that $\lvert f(x)-b \rvert < \varepsilon $ for all $x$ with $\lvert x - a \rvert <\delta$. Hence
$$ \int_A f(x) \, dx \geqslant \int_{|x-a|<\delta} f(x) \, dx \geqslant \int_{|x-a|<\delta} (b-\varepsilon) \, dx = (b-\varepsilon)V > 0, $$
where $V$ is the volume of $\lvert x - a \rvert <\delta$, and obviously positive. The first inequality is a consequence of $f(x) \geqslant 0$.

Comment: I could not see that the first inequality is a consequence of $f(x)\geq 0$. Could you explain better?

Comment: I forgot to add that the open ball needs to be contained in $A$ (if you can't do that, the theorem can be false). Then $\int_{A} = \int_{B} + \int_{A \setminus B}$, and the latter cannot be less than zero since the integral of a nonnegative function over any measurable set is nonnegative.

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks. And why it shows the result?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sure, I'm sorry. How your response justifies that $\int_{A} f(x)dx=0$ implies $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in A$?

Comment: I have shown that if the function is not zero, the integral is not zero. Therefore we cannot have the integral zero and the function not zero. Hence we must have your statement.

Comment: Perfectly! You use the contrapositive. Thank you.